# ebook framework for iphone

Tags: iphone

I've got a book that I'd like to publish as an app for the iphone.  Does anyone know of a free (or cheap) framework that I can use in order to achieve this?  In other words, I want to create a standalone XCODE project for my book that includes all the code needed for an iphone user to read the book as a standalone app.

I have seen O'Reilly use something but it doesn't appear to be freely available or on sale.  Any help or guidance that can be provided would be much appreciated.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What type of project I need to create for ibook Application?

Answer (score 2):

Drew McCormack [published a guide](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-xxx-developing-iphone) on MacResearch to how he created his [scientific scripting with Python ebook application](http://www.macresearch.org/first-tech-book-published-exclusively-iphone).  That might be one starting point for you.

However, I'd recommend taking a look at [self-publishing via Amazon's Kindle Store](https://dtp.amazon.com/mn/signin).  It looks remarkably easy to do (using simple HTML), and you'll be able to sell the book on any of Amazon's Kindle devices, as well as for the Kindle iPhone application.  These Kindle books seem to be selling [surprisingly well](http://www.earlyword.com/2009/05/08/bezos-kindle-e-book-sales-are-35-of-total-sales/).

Comment: I'd side with this. You'll be hitting a much more interested target audience than you would be just throwing your app out there on the app store. Knowing that you'll also be available on the kindle as well as the iPhone can only be considered a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

maybe convert the document to html and use Baker http://bakerframework.com/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what affordable means to you, you might try this: http://ebookapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of trying to answer the same question for myself. In addition to [Baker](http://bakerframework.com/) and [Laker](http://www.lakercompendium.com/), I've also found [Treesaver.js](http://treesaverjs.com/) and am considering using that with [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/).